# How to create lagged variables in Julia?

Tags: julia

Is there a function to create lagged variables in Julia without resorting any packages?

Specifically, I want to emulate the R's `embed` function in Julia.

```
> embed(1:8, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    2    1
[2,]    4    3    2
[3,]    5    4    3
[4,]    6    5    4
[5,]    7    6    5
[6,]    8    7    6
```

After a couple of hours of browsing Julia manual, I gave up looking for suitable function in Julia. This ugly function (by R standard) is what I have so far. Is there any built-in function or any room for improvement?

```
julia> function embed(x, k)
           n = length(x)
           m = zeros(n - k + 1, k)
           for i in 1:k
               m[:, i] = x[(k-i+1):(n-i+1)]
           end
           return m
       end
embed (generic function with 1 method)

julia> embed(1:8,3)
6x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 3.0  2.0  1.0
 4.0  3.0  2.0
 5.0  4.0  3.0
 6.0  5.0  4.0
 7.0  6.0  5.0
 8.0  7.0  6.0
```

Comment: Is this really a common operation?  You say that the code you wrote is "ugly" compared to R. But the actual R code either looks like this (and could be slow), or is (even worse) written in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dismiss `zeros` for [`cell`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays/#Base.cell) to skip initialization. You can also do

```
embed(x,k) = hcat([x[i+k-1:-1:i] for i in 1:length(x)-k+1]...)'
```

Explanation

- Create reverse stride indexes using `[i+k-1:-1:i]` and `for`
- Take that **list** of items, and make it the **arguments** of `hcat` by using `...`
- Concatenate the strides (passed as arguments)
- Transpose the result using `'`

EDIT: Assuming `length(x)` ⋙ `k`, you can also use:

```
embed(x,k) = hcat([x[k-i+1:length(x)-i+1] for i in 1:k]...)
```

Which gives the same results, but iterates less, and thus does less allocations.

Comment: The original is more readable, and probably faster. But it's an impressive one-liner! Note that you should (almost) never use the terribly-named `cell` arrays, since they will not allow Julia to infer types correctly. However, your code does correctly infer types.